# ng-model not selecting the radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input type radio inside a ng-repeat. 
The entire div is loaded in a popup, so i am accessing the controller property via parentScope.

```
<div ng-repeat="name in parentScope.PatientInfo">
      <input type="radio" id="select-radio-{{$index}}" ng-class="{'radio-btn':true, 'newpaymentmethod1' : true}" 
        ng-model="parentScope.nameObject"  name="object">
</div>
```

I am getting the value for `parentScope.PatientInfo`, but my input type radio is not getting selected by default or on click either. 
I tried giving `value and ng-value` to my input type radio, but all in vain.

Comment: Can you add your complete code?

Comment: what is there in nameObject?

Comment: in the controller... parentScope.PatientInfo and parentScope.nameObject... both are in same controller

Comment: you are not using `name ` iterator of ng-repeat ?, verify your `ng-model="parentScope.nameObject"`

Comment: I get an object.... {
    "name": "something"  
    "zipCode": "80166",
    "addressType": "shipToHome"
}

Comment: Did you try `ng-checked="true"`?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.selected = {
    "name": "",
    "zipCode": "",
    "addressType": "",
    "message": ""
  };
  $scope.items = [{
    "name": "newyork",
    "zipCode": "80166",
    "addressType": "shipToHome",
    "message": "test"
  }, {
    "name": "toronto",
    "zipCode": "80166",
    "addressType": "shipToHome",
    "message": "test"
  }, {
    "name": "california",
    "zipCode": "80166",
    "addressType": "shipToHome",
    "message": "test"
  }];
  $scope.MessageDelivery = function(name) {
    $scope.selected.message = "Will be Delivered to " + name;

  };
  $scope.getItems = function() {
    return $scope.items;
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div>Which one?</div>
    <label class="radio" ng-repeat="item in getItems()">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="selected.name" name="itemOptions" ng-change="MessageDelivery(item.name)" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}} - {{item.zipCode}} - {{item.addressType}}
        </label>
    <hr />
    <div>You picked: {{selected.name}} - {{selected.message}} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```